# For anomaly detection on blockchain networks, what are some key differences between Ethereum and Bitcoin?

Tags: transactions, security, yellow-paper

I'm currently exploring anomaly detection techniques on the Ethereum networks. From existing research papers available, I realized that anomaly detection research have been mostly done separately between the 2.

What are some differences (and maybe also similarities) between Ethereum and Bitcoin for anomaly detection techniques?